# Day hour Heatmap - Colors not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

This is my code for a d3.js heatmap chart and the problem is with colors. Took the code from http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084 and modified it for reading from a php, which echo data in json format. 
so after modifying it, I am getting a heatmap with all grids in black colors with some white gaps.

I am new to d3 charts, kindly excuse in case of any minor mistakes you find in code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkVLz.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      rect.bordered {
        stroke: #E6E6E6;
        stroke-width:2px;   
      }

      text.mono {
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Consolas, courier;
        fill: #aaa;
      }

      text.axis-workweek {
        fill: #000;
      }

      text.axis-worktime {
        fill: #000;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30 },
          width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 430 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24),
          legendElementWidth = gridSize*2,
          buckets = 9,
          colors = ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"], // alternatively colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9]
          days = ["Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
          times = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a", "11a", "12a", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p", "12p"];
         // datasets = ["data1.tsv", "data2.tsv"];


 
      d3.json("heatmaptry2.php", function(error, data) {


  data.forEach(function(d) {
  console.log(d);
  day= +d.day; 
  hour= +d.hour;
  value= +d.value; 
  }); 
   var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile();
 
      var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
          .data(days)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-5," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
            .attr("class", function (d, i) { return ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis"); });

      var timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
          .data(times)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function(d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * gridSize; })
            .attr("y", 0)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -5)")
            .attr("class", function(d, i) { return ((i >= 7 && i <= 16) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis"); });
    
   var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".hour")
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour) * gridSize; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.day ) * gridSize; })
          .attr("rx", 4)
          .attr("ry", 4)
          .attr("class", "hour bordered")
          .attr("width", gridSize)
          .attr("height", gridSize)
          .style("fill", colors[0]);

      heatMap.transition().duration(1000)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });

      heatMap.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.value; });
     heatMap.exit().remove();     

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), function(d) { return d; });

          legend.enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "legend");

          legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
            .attr("y", height)
            .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
            .attr("height", gridSize / 2)
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

          legend.append("text")
            .attr("class", "mono")
            .text(function(d) { return "≥ " + Math.round(d); })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) { return legendElementWidth * i; })
            .attr("y", height + gridSize);

          legend.exit().remove();

        });  
      

      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not block-quote all your code.  Instead use the code button to format it correctly, which appears like this: **{}**

Comment: just edited. Hope its fine now.

Comment: can you also paste JSON data is sent via php

Comment: [{"day":"0","hour":"0","value":"11"},{"day":"0","hour":"1","value":"3"},{"day":"0","hour":"2","value":"2"},{"day":"0","hour":"3","value":"1"},{"day":"0","hour":"4","value":"1"},{"day":"0","hour":"6","value":"3"},{"day":"0","hour":"8","value":"3"},{"day":"0","hour":"9","value":"14"},{"day":"0","hour":"10","value":"19"},{"day":"0","hour":"11","value":"42"},{"day":"0","hour":"12","value":"44"},{"day":"0","hour":"13","value":"35"},{"day":"0","hour":"14","value":"44"},{"day":"0","hour":"15","value":"37"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile();
```

it should have been (you are not setting the domain)

```
 var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
              .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })])
              .range(colors);
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yaLLnY7u06zfA28LQw64?p=preview)

Comment: you can accept it as answer here is how it works http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work